# How to group by with count if rows are not present?

Tags: mysql

For example, table `category_description` having following rows

```
name    | category_id | nav_id
History | 62          |  1
Romance | 61          |  1
mysql   | 59          |  1
mssql   | 60          |  1
```

Then `product_to_category` having following rows,

```
product_id | category_id
 55        |   62
 54        |   62
```

I'm trying to count the number of product from product_to_category table using below query

```
select name,count(a.category_id) from category_description a, 
product_to_category b 
where a.category_id = b.category_id group by name;
```

I'm getting the following result

```
+---------+----------------------+
| name    | count(a.category_id) |
+---------+----------------------+
| History |                    2 |
+---------+----------------------+
```

But I'm trying to count the null data also for example I have except the following output

```
+---------+----------------------+
| name    | count(a.category_id) |
+---------+----------------------+
| History |                     2|
|  mysql  |                     0|
|  mssql  |                     0|
|Romance  |                     0|
+---------+----------------------+
```

I don't know from where need to change.

Comment: You are using a join syntax that was made redundant in 1992. Why? If you had used proper joins, you might have become aware that you must decide between `INNER JOIN`  and `LEFT OUTER JOIN` and what the difference between them is. You would naturally have chosen the outer join, because this is exactly what they exist for, and wouldn't have had to ask :-)

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I'm new to mysql. Now I'm learning it. I had the following task so I started learn join. Thanks your comment I'll concentrate on other join function :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select name,count(b.category_id) 
from category_description a
LEFT JOIN product_to_category b  ON a.category_id = b.category_id
group by name;
```

Try above query.

You don't need to add where condition, instead of that I had put that condition over **`ON CLAUSE`** and instead of **`INNER JOIN`** you can try using **`LEFT JOIN`**.

Comment: While the answer seems to solve the problem, it would be nice for the OP and for the future readers to add a short explanation about why it works and why the query posted in the question doesn't work.

Comment: @SagarGangwal All other rows giving the count as `1` except History. Not giving `0`

Comment: @Sagar Gangwal: *full join*? That is incorrect. OP is using an outdated join syntax which is a *cross join* in the first place. The where clause then renders this an *inner join*. `full join` on the other hand is short for `full outer join`.

Comment: Yes, of course it is a left outer join that is needed here and your query is correct. But you are saying that OP should use this instead of a full join. Nobody ever used or mentioned a full (outer) join here. What you probably wanted to say is "and instead of an INNER JOIN you can try using LEFT JOIN".